# How to add row to calculate (each column mean - grand mean) in R?

Tags: r, datatable, mean

This is my data

```
Env<- c("Env1","Env2")
Genotype1<- c(20,25)
Genotype2<- c(30,35)
dataB<- data.frame(Env, Genotype1,Genotype2)

dataB$Avg <- rowMeans (dataB %>% select(-Env))
dataB <- rbind(dataB, c("Avg", colMeans(dataB %>% select(-Env))))
dataB$Avg <- as.numeric(dataB$Avg)
dataB$Env_effect <- dataB$Avg - dataB$Avg[nrow(dataB)]

Env       Genotype1 Genotype2  Avg    Env_effect
1 Env1        20        30     25.0      -2.5
2 Env2        25        35     30.0       2.5
3 Avg       22.5      32.5     27.5       0.0
```

I calculated mean per row and column respectively, and added one column (Env_effect) to calculate (mean of each ENV  - grand mean). This is environmrntal effect.

Now as the same way, I want to add one row to calculate (mean of each genotype  - grand mean) like below to calculate genotypic effect.

```
Env       Genotype1 Genotype2  Avg    Env_index
1 Env1        20        30     25.0      -2.5
2 Env2        25        35     30.0       2.5
3 Avg       22.5      32.5     27.5       0.0
4 G_effect    -5         5
```

Could you let me know how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Which problems did you encounter?

Comment: I want to add one row (G_effect) to calculate (mean of each genotype - grand mean).

Answer (score 0):

We may have to expand the data and do the difference based on subsetting on 'Avg' value of 'Env'

```
dataB[4, 1:3] <- c("G_effect", as.list(type.convert(dataB[
    dataB$Env == "Avg", 2:3]) - dataB$Avg[dataB$Env == "Avg"]))
```

-output

```
> dataB
       Env Genotype1 Genotype2  Avg Env_effect
1     Env1        20        30 25.0       -2.5
2     Env2        25        35 30.0        2.5
3      Avg      22.5      32.5 27.5        0.0
4 G_effect        -5         5   NA         NA
```